# How to go from connected with localhost on a device to connecting via IP on public internet? (socket-io, express, phaser)

Tags: express, socket.io, portforwarding, static-ip-address

I am attempting to develop an online browser game, and though I have no intention of buying a domain or cloud hosting it, I want to be able to run a server on my computer and have people play the online game by connecting via browser on other devices, on other networks. I have developed the game using socket-io, express, and phaser, and I have reached the point where I can play the game, with full multiplayer functionality between different tabs on the computer running the server. I am struggling to figure out the code and port forwarding changes to make it work over the public internet.

Reducing it to the bare bones, I have a server.js file in the root as follows:

```
const server = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(server);
const host = 'localhost'; const port = 3000;

const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: { origin: `http://${host}:8080` }
  });

  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
      console.log('A user connected: ' + socket.id);
      socket.on('disconnect', function () { console.log('A user disconnected: ' + socket.id); });
  });

  http.listen(port, host, function () {
    console.log('Server started!');
});
```

And in a client directory there is a index.html that calls the following game.js script:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const hostname = 'localhost'; const port = 3000;
let serverAddress = `http://${hostname}:${port}`;

export default class Game extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super({ key: 'Game' });
    }

    create() {
        this.socket = io(serverAddress);
        this.socket.on('connect', function () { console.log('Connected!'); });
    }
}
```

From these, I run `npm start` in both the root and client directories. When opening `http://localhost:8080/` in a browser I get an acknowledgement by the server process that a user connects, and an acknowledgement in the browser console that the webpage is connected.

I have tried port forwarding to make sure that socket-io can send and receive publicly. I don't have a router but I going to my modem settings I added ipv4 forwarding for the port `3000` and my PC's local ip (`10.0.0.58`) with TCP and UDP. I can't really get my head around the relationship between port forwarding, the ports `3000` and `8080`, and the Nodejs server and client processes.

I have tried changing in the code to replace localhost with my public ipv4 address (`xxx.xxx.xxx.234`), which whatismyipaddress.com reckons is probably static, but the server console identifies http.listen() as throwing an error so this doesn't get off the ground, and this happens even with Windows Defender Firewall disabled. No matter what I set the ports or the hosts to in server.js and game.js, when I open another device on a separate network and enter `xxx.xxx.xxx.234` or `xxx.xxx.xxx.234:3000` or `xxx.xxx.xxx.234:8080` or anything I can't get any connection.

What do I change to get it working? When using a browser on another device and network, should I expect to be connecting on `xxx.xxx.xxx.234:8080` or `xxx.xxx.xxx.234:3000` and why? Why does the browser on my local machine not load my game at `xxx.xxx.xxx.234:3000`, but it does at `xxx.xxx.xxx.234:8080` despite the fact that 8080 doesn't appear anywhere in my code other than a cors fix? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here because I'm just a self taught hobbyist, but it'd be great to figure this out so I can get back to coding the game!

Comment: You absolutely *should* buy a domain if you want other people to play the game. (Where and how to host the server is a separate question though)

Answer (score 0):

well this is no phaser issue this is more a Network issue/ question. That said, for others to be able to play the game, there are somethings you need too look out for:

- your [ISP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) must not be blocking the ports you want to use( some ISP block incoming traffic ), depending on your provider you might not be able
- your ISP must give you a static ip Adresse (if you hav a dynamic on it is more difficult, and you would need to use a service like noip.com)
- your "router" must be configured to forward ports (only the specific ones you need) to your Computer's IP
- your Computer needs to have a static local IP so that the router can forward the ports.
- than the code has to reflect this new ip/host Situation.

So now specific to your question,

- first your game uses two ports **8080** for the webserver/webpage and **3000** for socket.io. so those two port need to be accessible form the Internet. test it with *https://your-external-ip:8080*. (bzw.: if I remember correctly websockets might not work on non **https** Websites, if not **localhost**, you might need to enable ssl, chekc the browser console, it there are errors)
- if everthing works, you just need to change in your code, the host/hostname **localhost** too *your-external-ip*. **BUT only** in the client side code.

> if you have issue in some step, always check the browser/developer console, for errors.

> just to be clear you start your game on port 8080, port 3000 is ise by your game in the Background, thats why you will need to forward both.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I have got it working on devices connected to the local network, so I think all the port forwarding is correct. I have also added rules to both window and my modem's firewall to allow incoming packets, but despite this I always get `Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available xxx.xxx.xxx.234:3000`. How can I check where the problem is in the system, be it my ISP, my port forwarding settings, my system firewall, the modem firewall, etc. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: I update my answer, you need only to update the hostname on the client side. Why you have the error I not sure, Does the website show up, when you open it with the external ip? if not it is very likely your ISP is blocking the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that the issue was my ISP, (Belong), which does not offer static IPs, uses CGNAT, and does not offer ipv6. I ended up getting it working after a lot of hair pulling by following this tutorial very closely:

https://www.reddit.com/r/selfhosted/comments/u8n5hz/how_to_bypass_cgnat_and_expose_your_server_to_the/